# What should I do with third-party jar resource in Native mode in Quarkus Extension

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native, quarkus-extension

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/xxxxx");
```

I am writing a Quarkus Extension, a third-party jar whose META-INF/xxxxx is null in native mode but there are no problems with jvm mode.
If you know the solution or the related documents, please let me know, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make GraalVM aware of the resource you are going to access by doing the following:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes=META-INF/xxxxx
```

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#including-resources) for more information.

Comment: I solved that with buildItem,Thank you.   I would like to ask whether qaurkus native can recognize jni-config.json, whether parameters need to be added, and whether there are relevant documents

Comment: `jni-config.json` files are automatically taken into account by GraalVM when placed in `META-INF/native-image/${project.grouId}/${project.artifactId}/`. See https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/overview/BuildConfiguration/